# Library in SAS already mapped, but not assigned

Tags: sas

The libname is already mapped with shortcut and everything, but if I try to run my code using the libname I got the error that the libname is not assigned.

So, to use it, I simply open the server tree, rmb in the library in question and assign and works perfectly. Is there a way to incorporate the assignment in the code? I can't declare the libname again, I don't know the path.

I've tried to simply declare the libname again, but it has a shortcut that I'm too rookie to declare again, I'm afraid to make a big mistake and mess up with the DB.

I'm using sas enterprise guide, in the left corner there is a box labelled servers +servers +SASApp +libraries, the library in question isn't assigned, so it's in white, after being assigner it turns yellow.

Comment: What tool are you using that is showing "server tree"?  Enterprise Guide perhaps?

Comment: It is good practice to name the tools you use and share code and log snippets.

Comment: I'm using sas enterprise guide, in the left corner there is a box labelled servers +servers +SASApp +libraries, the library in question isn't assigned, so it's in white, after being assigner it turns yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those libraries in white are predefined in the metadata server. Since you already mentioned that you can right-click on the library and select Assign to use it, that means the resource is set up correctly and you have the necessary permissions to use the resource.

Instead of right-clicking, you can use the libname meta engine to assign the resource.

```
libname mylib meta lib=metalib;
```

This tells SAS to use the predefined library metalib and assign it to the libref mylib in your current session. In this example, metalib refers to the library you see in the list in the lower left corner of EG of the Servers tab.

Comment: I actually had to use 'library' instead of 'lib', 'lib' is not a valid argument, but just your explanation was enough to put me in the right track, thank you so much!

Comment: It assigns, but when I try to use it, it doesn't work, I feel I'm in the right direction, I'll try more to find on my own with the thing I've learned, maybe I'll create another topic with more information. Thank you again.